# Why won't my GLUT window close?

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm having a problem with GLUT. I'm trying to make my program close when a certain button is pressed or the mouse button is clicked. That is ESC and the right click.

I have no idea why it's not working, here is the code below

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <glut.h>
#include <iostream>

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);
void mouse (int button, int state, int x, int y);
void render(void);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); //Position of the window
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480); //Screen Size
    glutCreateWindow("Greeting Card");  //Creates the window and names it

    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    glutMainLoop();   //Finished, now render

}

void keyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y) {
    if (c == 27) {
        exit(0);
    }
}

void mouse (int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
        exit(0);
    }
```

Here are the errors

```
Error   3   error C3861: 'exit': identifier not found   i:\computer graphics\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp    31  1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   error C3861: 'exit': identifier not found   i:\computer graphics\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp    25  1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   1   error C2381: 'exit' : redefinition; __declspec(noreturn) differs    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\stdlib.h 360 1   ConsoleApplication1
```

i've included #include  and still getting the same errors :(

Answer (score 1):

exit() is defined in

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

so you must include that header. This always comes handy: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Comment: What's in your stdafx.h? Also, for cstdlib, you must either do `using namespace std` or call exit() with `std::exit()`

Comment: The only thing in stdafx.h is #include "stdafx.h" D:

Comment: Can you replace your code and errors in your original post with your new code and errors?

Comment: If your code is exactly the same, that is your problem. I said that you must include the cstdlib header and then either call `exit()` as `std::exit()` or declare `using namespace std;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Okay cool, I've tried your suggestions and I still get Error 1

Comment: Can you update your code now? Also, try commenting out all of your glut function calls, and remove the `#include <glut.h>` temporarily. Then try recompiling and see what errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

`exit` is actually defined in `#include <iostream>` as far as I know.

I've gotten the program to work by including iostream.

Never forget: If you don't add the namespace std:: you need to add it before your `exit()`.